# EXEC an INSERT with a dynamic Schema TSQL SSMS

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, ssms

I know that's a little bit much, but I'm searching for a solution since 4 days. I just want to EXEC a INSERT, but I always get some cryptic Error Messages in SSMS

INPUT(variables are wrong so the ErrorLog should get filled):

```
USE [Tfs_GitInterface]
GO
DECLARE @return_value int
EXEC    @return_value = [dbo].[spInsertChangeLevel2]
        @repositoryName = N'asdasd',
        @commitId = 213123,
        @changeLevel = N'asda'
SELECT  'Return Value' = @return_value
GO
```

Stored Procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[spInsertChangeLevel2]
-- Add the parameters for the stored procedure here
@repositoryName [nvarchar](256),
@commitId [binary](20),
@changeLevel [nvarchar](400)
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    DECLARE @repId [int]
    DECLARE @commitIdValid [int];
    DECLARE @errorOccured [BIT] = 0;
    DECLARE @schema [nvarchar](400) = 'dbo';
    DECLARE @schemaPlusTable [nvarchar](400) = @schema + '.tbl_ErrorLog';
    DECLARE @changeErrorMsg [nvarchar](400) = 'Wrong ChangeLevel';
    DECLARE @changeSQL [nvarchar](MAX);

    BEGIN TRY
        IF
        (@changeLevel <> 'NewFeature' AND @changeLevel <> 'Patch' AND @changeLevel <>'BreakingChange')
        BEGIN
            PRINT 'Wrong ChangeLevel';

            EXEC('INSERT INTO [' + @schema + '].[tbl_ErrorLog] ( [repositoryName], [commitId], [changeLevel], [error], [timestamp] )
                  VALUES ( "test" , ' + @commitId + ' , ' + @changeLevel + ' , ' + @changeErrorMsg + ' , SYSDATETIME() )');

            SET @errorOccured = 1;
        END

        IF NOT EXISTS
        (SELECT InternalRepositoryId FROM dbo.tbl_GitRepository WHERE Name = @repositoryName)
        BEGIN
            PRINT 'Repository-Name ist nicht bekannt'
            INSERT INTO [dbo].[tbl_ErrorLog]
                    ([repositoryName]
                    ,[commitId]
                    ,[changeLevel]
                    ,[error]
                    ,[timestamp])
            VALUES 
                    (@repositoryName
                    ,@commitId
                    ,@changeLevel
                    ,'Repository-Name is unknown'
                    ,SYSDATETIME())
            SET @errorOccured = 1;
        END

        SELECT @repId = InternalRepositoryId FROM
        dbo.tbl_GitRepository WHERE
        Name = @repositoryName;

        IF NOT EXISTS
        (SELECT CommitId FROM dbo.tbl_GitCommit WHERE CommitId = @commitId AND InternalRepositoryId = @repId)
        BEGIN
            PRINT 'CommitId is unknown'
            INSERT INTO [dbo].[tbl_ErrorLog]
                    ([repositoryName]
                    ,[commitId]
                    ,[changeLevel]
                    ,[error]
                    ,[timestamp])
            VALUES 
                    (@repositoryName
                    ,@commitId
                    ,@changeLevel
                    ,'CommitId is unknown'
                    ,SYSDATETIME())
            SET @errorOccured = 1;
        END

        IF(@errorOccured = 1) RETURN 0;

        INSERT INTO [dbo].[tbl_ChangeLevel]
              ([InternalRepositoryId]
              ,[CommitId]
              ,[ChangeLevel])
         VALUES
              (@repId
              ,@commitId
              ,@changeLevel)
    END TRY
    BEGIN CATCH
    PRINT 'Msg: ' + ERROR_MESSAGE();
    PRINT  ERROR_LINE();
    PRINT  ERROR_NUMBER();
    PRINT 'Procedure: ' + ERROR_PROCEDURE();
    PRINT  ERROR_STATE();
    RETURN 0;
    END CATCH
    RETURN 1;
END
```

It's actually pretty simple stuff, this stored procedure tests if the 3 variables are legit/known and if so, its inserts them into the tbl_ChangeLevel-table. For every wrong variable its creates a row in the tbl_ErrorLog-table, that means either we have one new row in tbl_ChangeLevel or 1-3 in tbl_ErrorLog.

At the moment I changed the first test for an error at ChangeLevel to a dynamic EXEC so the schema(@schema) can be changed. I tried literally everything here. At first I used sp_executesql and EXECUTE, but nothing worked and now when I debug this, it catches an error:

Wrong ChangeLevel
Msg: Incorrect syntax near '̀'.

2

102

1

(1 row(s) affected)

And yes thats not dirt on your screen -> '̀' <- its one of these things à, but its no where in my code, I already searched row for row.... I had already other Errors like an Enter-Symbol, " " or "." I'm frustrated :/ Pls help

Comment: You need more quotes to have quotes in your actual insert. For example this: `' + @changeLevel + '` should become this: `''' + @changeLevel + '''`. Try printing out your insert instead of executing it. Also keep in mind that the way you are currently building your string, if one of your parameters gets a `NULL` value your entire result will end up as `NULL`.

Comment: Just noticed you're insert `"test"` with double quotes. This should be 2 single quotes as well `''test''`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must have copy paste part of your query from outlook or other source. Other sources have different encoding format. 
If you have text editor like Notepad++ or ultraedit, change your query encoding to **UTF-8 without BOM**.

If the problem still persists, I would recommend to rewrite the query in SSMS query window.